# Setting timer with seek bar

Tags: java, android, string-comparison, android-seekbar

I have an app in which I have used minutes and seconds as a textview that changes with the dragging of seek bar and it is working fine. My only problem is that when it reaches to 10 minutes (I have set max to 600 which is ten minutes) it should be shown like this e.g 10:00 but unfortunately it is shown in like this 10:0 
I have tested it in both emulator and genymotion below is my code

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBarController);
    final TextView timerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerTextview);

    seekBar.setMax(600);
    seekBar.setProgress(30);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

            int minutes = progress / 60;
            int seconds = progress - minutes * 60;


            String secondString = Integer.toString(seconds);

            if (secondString == "0") {

                secondString = "00";

            }
                timerTextView.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + secondString);

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it in the debugger and check what are the values of your variables when you reach 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
if (seconds == 0) {
    secondString = "00";
}
```

or

```
if (secondString.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
    secondString = "00";
}
```

String comparison might have some issue!

Comment: Thank you it helped me :) but can you please understand me what was the logic why isn't string worked in that case?

Comment: @Rumaan The simple reason is Strings are not compared with == operator . There is one specific method to do so. See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Also never compare strings with `==` because `String` is an `Object`, instead use `equals()`. For example `if (secondString.equals("0"))`, but [android_griezmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40741030/7177329) should be sufficient.

Another solution without checks would be:

```
timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
```

because I wonder what happens on 5:00, 6:00 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just debug and check whether you are entering into the if condition. If not, try comparing using

```
      if (secondString.equals("0")) { secondString = "00";  }
```

Also check if you have set a maxLength attribute in the xml of TextView.Sometimes that may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
secondString=="0"
```

is work in cpp .
in Java/Android you should write

```
if (secondString.equals("0")) { secondString = "00";  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression to identify a single digit.

```java
if (secondString.matches("\\d") ) {
    secondString = "0" + secondString;
}
```